# How to rename multiple columns in simplified way

Tags: python, pandas

The new column names are stored an array 'IDs'.

I want to replace the column name of df accordingly

'0' -> IDs[0],  '1' -> IDs[1], '31' -> IDs[30]

Currently, I'm using this way to rename to columns.

```
df.columns = [IDs[0], IDs[1], ... , IDs[29], IDs[30]]
```

However, there are over 30 columns. Is there any way to simplify the code?

Edit: I found the previous content is misleading so I modify the question

Comment: Wouldn't `df.columns = [IDs[num] for num in range(30)]+[IDs[-1]]` work?

Comment: Thank you, it works but I use len(IDs) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention **array**, you can use [`np.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
n = 30
df.columns = np.hstack((IDs[:n], IDs[-1]))
```

Such an assignment is natural with Pandas, where indices are stored internally as NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list slicing:

```
df.columns = IDs[:30] + [IDs[-1]]
```